# Launching my debug MVC3 application opens a specific .cshtml file in the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In Visual Studio when I press `F5` in this particular MVC3 project, it opens:

```
localhost:36185/Views/Auction/Details.cshtml
```

When in any other project, when I press `F5` it correctly open the `Home/Index` action method:

```
http://localhost:36185
```

Why is this opening a specific View instead of using the correct Home/Index action? What setting is interfering?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Project properties => Web => Start Action

and take your pick

[image]

Comment: @SergioTapia I can't tell you how to get to an *action* unless I know your route-table; however, you can enter any url (without the host/port) in Specific Page (including a blank entry for site-root)

Comment: You can also just select "Specific Page" and leave the field empty and it would load your default route.

Comment: _Sanity_ is **RIGHT**! For years I've been dealing with this VS nuance and would just stop the debugger, select a code file tab (as opposed to an active `.cshtml` tab), and start the debugger again. Ugh :S Fantastic tip and one of the 2 options mentioned should be the default option honestly.

Comment: I disagree... I would advocate for "Start URL" and point it to your IIS route. Otherwise, your application will not launch; you must browse to it via URL bar or IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the solution given by Marc Gravell. If that doesn't work, you might want to check the Global.ascx file for routing configuration.