# ASP MVC 2 with asp.net development server won't load default controller & action for an empty route

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This used to work fine, but recently it refuse to load the default page for an empty route, instead it lists directory contents.

for example

`http://localhost:1234/` should take me to the same page as `http://localhost:1234/Home/Index` assuming global.asax hasn't been modified, however recently it just takes me to "Directory List -- /" and lists out the content of the project folder.

This is using the ASP.NET Development Server. The sites work fine when deployed into IIS on a server.

Does anybody have any ideas, this is really annoying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error I've determined that this is caused by the IBM RTC plug-in, when disabled it works normally.

I find this very surprising, but I've double checked and it is definitely that!

Answer (score 0):

I would check the project settings like suggested on this other question:

[Launching my debug MVC3 application opens a specific .cshtml file in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051036/launching-my-debug-mvc3-application-opens-a-specific-cshtml-file-in-the-browser/8051061)

Comment: Hi, the correct page is opening, and its not just when the site is first started, it is whenever i navigate to the root url. The request doesn't seem to make it to the mvc app and just returns the directory contents.

Comment: If it happens also when you navigate to the URL (I missed that on the original post) then I am baffled.